# Bottom navigation bar - rectangle action button

Tags: android, floating-action-button, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android, material-components

Using `google.android.material`:

1. Is it possible to make action button rectangle ?
2. Is it possible to move it a little higher / lower ?

I am talking about the middle circle button.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **`app:shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute to achieve a square button and the **`app:fabCradleVerticalOffset`** attribute to change the distance of the FAB to the `BottomAppBar`.

Something like:

```
  <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
         app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="16dp"
         app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="0dp"
         app:fabCradleMargin="0dp"
          ..>


      <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
          app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/SquareFloatingShapeOVerlay"
          ../>
```

with:

```
  <style name="SquareFloatingShapeOVerlay" parent="">
    <item name="cornerSize">0dp</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

If you want a **rectangular** shape you can use a **`ExtendedFloatingActionButton`** instead of the `FloatingActionButton`.

Something like:

```
  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
      app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar"
      app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlayExtended"
      ../>
```

with:

```
  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlayExtended" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">0dp</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

**Note:** it requires the version **`1.1.0`** of the Material Components Library.

Comment: and is there any workaround for negative offset, as I would like to have this FAB much lower than `0dp` ?

Comment: Unfortunately `app:fabCradleVerticalOffset` must be a **positive** value You can't use a negative offset. The only workaround is to remove the `app:layout_anchor`      and add something like: `android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"` and `android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: If you are using `FloatingActionButton`

```
app:borderWidth="0dp"

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:elevation="@dimen/fab_elevation"
    android:background="#000000"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/fab_anim"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Hope this will help !

Answer (score 0):

To change the shape of the Floating Action Button, you can create a separate resource file in the drawable folder for eg: `shape.xml` as-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
```

and then in Floating Action Button add the following property:

```
 android:background="@drawable/shape"
```

Also, you can use margin to move it higher.

Answer (score 0):

Use `elevation` attribute to FAB

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_items" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:elevation="8dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
```